# Where statement to exclude records but only if another column equals x

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to exclude records from a sql select statement with the most granular column in my salesfacts table which is invoice number, but the problem is that the invoice number could have been used in previous years (I checked there are 26 duplications in the table). I know this is a business rule problem but I don't have the ability to change it.

The code I'm trying to exclude this from is part of a long sql statement with three main parts that are combined with union statements, the three parts being: accounts receivable, open orders, and journal entries. In this instance I'm trying to exclude the records from the 'accounts receivable' section.

So for this instance I'm trying to exclude 5 invoice numbers from the accounts receivable part but only if they occur in March 2019. (so this ensures I'm not excluding duplicate invoice numbers that may or may not exist in previous periods). Maybe I'm paranoid and it'll probably be fine as the chances are slim that a record I want to exclude is actually repeated, but if the business rules allow repeats I don't want to risk having unintended results.

I'd like to find a clean way of adding these to a simple where statement vs using 'except' because I will have to exclude other records in the future and I don't know if  multiple excepts and unions would work.

Not working:

```
Select invoicedate,invoiceno
from saleshistory
where (invoiceno != '1001' and invoicedate = '2011-01-14')
```

The above is showing all records with invoicedate 2011-01-14 except invoiceno 1001. I want the code to show all records but invoiceno 1001 if it ocurred on 2011-01-14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement can be written like this:

```
Select invoicedate,invoiceno
from saleshistory
where (invoiceno <> '1001' or invoicedate <> '2011-01-14')
```

because you want to negate this:

```
invoiceno = '1001' and invoicedate = '2011-01-14'
```

so:

```
NOT (invoiceno = '1001' and invoicedate = '2011-01-14')
```

is equivalent to

```
invoiceno <> '1001' or invoicedate <> '2011-01-14'
```

Comment: I knew there was a simple answer! Thank you. Apparently I need to go back to my old logic textbooks. I combined the multiple records with 'not in' and it works the same

Comment: Logic, Boolean algebra etc. unforgetable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand you:

```
Select invoicedate,invoiceno
from saleshistory
where (invoiceno != '1001' or ( invoiceno = '1001' and invoicedate = '2011-01-14'))
```

With this one you may get all the records with invoiceno different of 1001 in any date, and the records with invoiceno 1001 and date 2011-01-14.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to exclude 5 invoice numbers from the accounts receivable part but only if they occur in March 2019

The following implements this logic:

```
select sh.*
from saleshistory sh
where not (invoiceno in ( . . . ) and  -- list of invoice numbers here
           invoicedate >= '2019-03-01' and
           invoicedate < '2019-04-01'
          );
```

Given the description in the text, I'm baffled why you have the constant `'2011-01-14'` in your example query.